# Can't post facebook video URL via facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Currently I have a strange problem with the facebook Graph API.

I am using the facebook/php-sdk-v4 version 5.3

All works fine with it, I can post URLs with it to users wall. But when I want to post a facebook video URL, no URL will be posted.

For example: I want to post the following URL to users feed via SDK:

https://www.facebook.com/hdadd/videos/10157576067105265/

I filled link data like for every other URL

```
$linkData = [
              'link' => 'https://www.facebook.com/hdadd/videos/10157576067105265/',
              'message' => 'This is a test',
            ];
```

API said, that the post was posted successfully. But when I look at the post, the only thing which appears it the message "This is a test" without the link to the facebook video. When I am doing it with another URL, it works properly.

What do I do wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: _“API said, that the post was posted successfully”_ – not for me, I get an error data structure that contains `"error_user_msg": "Sorry, the post that you're sharing couldn't be loaded. It may have been recently deleted."` This seems wrong though, because I can share the video manually - so I suggest you file a bug report. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: Just tried it. I get a success response with a node ID: Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphNode Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( [id] => 828061167241461_1125413837506191 ) ). But now link in Post appears.